# TypeScript bug with String.fromCharCode vs '0x'

Tags: typescript

I need any suggestion to pass this problem please!
Error in :

> ('0x' + p1);

Error log :

```
 TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
```

Code :

```
export function encodeString(str): any {
  // first we use encodeURIComponent to get percent-encoded UTF-8,
  // then we convert the percent encodings into raw bytes which
  // can be fed into btoa.
  return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g,
    function toSolidBytes(match, p1) {
      return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
    }));
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this:

```
return String.fromCharCode(parseInt('0x' + p1, 16));
```

You need to convert the UTF-8 code string into an integer using parseInt (`16` means hexadecimal). Then, you pass it to the String.fromCharCode() function.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I needed to check , oh yes i forgot this ts role about parse!